# Clojure: difference between applying directly or by way of a function

Tags: clojure

The aim is to play with a slight modification of the Caesar cipher.
First a function to move a character:

```
    (defn move-char [c shift idx encode-or-decode]
      (let [ch (int c) val (mod (* encode-or-decode (+ shift idx)) 26)]
       (cond 
        (and (>= ch (int \A)) (<= ch (int \Z))) (char (+ (mod (+ val (- (int ch) (int \A))) 26) (int \A)))
        (and (>= ch (int \a)) (<= ch (int \z))) (char (+ (mod (+ val (- (int ch) (int \a))) 26) (int \a)))
        :else c)))
```

Then a function to map the last one to a string:

```
(defn move-shift-aux [str shift encode-or-decode]
  (map-indexed (fn [idx item] (move-char item shift idx encode-or-decode)) str))

`(move-shift-aux "I should have known..." 1 1)` returns
(\J \space \v \l \t \a \s \l \space \r \l \h \r \space \z \d \f \o \g \. \. \.)
```

and if I write:

```
(apply str (move-shift-aux "I should have known..." 1 1))
```

I get what I want:

```
"J vltasl rlhr zdfog..."
```

But if I define:

```
(defn moving-shift [str shift]
  (apply str (move-shift-aux str shift 1)))

(moving-shift "I should have known..." 1)
```

I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn, compiling:(caesar\core.clj:29:44)
```

I don't understand why the compiler exception while it does work fine when applying directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing the `str` symbol from `clojure.core` with your `str` parameter. Inside `moving-shift`'s scope, `str` refers to `"I should have known..."` and not `clojure.core/str`, hence when you call your `apply` function, you get a `ClassCastException`, stating that a string is not a function.
Use another name for your string parameter.